# Getting the value of local storage with Observable is not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, local-storage

Hi I am trying to get the value from local storage  by using observable but it is not working.

My previous code was:

```js
const isManager= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isManager'));
console.log('isManager', isManager);
this.doNavigation(isManager);
```

But I change it in to this for continously reading value:

```
of(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isManager'))).pipe(
      takeWhile(() => this.alive),
      map((isManager: boolean) => {
        console.log('isManager', isManager);
        this.doNavigation(isManager);
      })
    );
```

The problem is that it is not going inside the map body and there is a value present in local stroage regarding this field.

Comment: Where are you subscribing to the observable? Are you using the async pipe or is the code snippet above in a function? If its in a function you will have to call `.subscribe()` at the end of it.

Comment: If you want to use local storage item's value as observable stream, `BehaviourSubject` would be better solution.

Comment: @Jovana Your suggestion looks good. Can you write detail answer for your purposed solution ?

Comment: @robi sure, I've added my answer. I hope it helps. If there's any part that requires more explanation, feel free to comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is an option to continuously read value from local storage, for that to work, you'd need to be able to subscribe to local storage item's value and that's just not possible.

What you've done in your solution is created Observable containing only one value (current local storage item's value), so after you subscribe to that method you'd only get current value, but it wouldn't change no matter if local storage item's value changes.

Since there is no direct way to subscribe to local storage, you can use service with `BehaviourSubject` which will constantly have stored the newest local storage item's value. That way wherever you subscribe to `BehaviourSubject` all dependent elements will always get the newest value from stream.

This is what the service which handles local storage should look like:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class LocalStorageService {
 private isManager$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

 constructor(){
   // get current value from local storage
   isManager = localStorage.getItem('isManager');

   // set stream's last value to local storage item's value
   // this way when service is initialized, isManager$'s value will be set to current local storage value
   this.isManager$.next(isManager as boolean);
 }

 setIsManager(value):void {
   // sets isManager$'s value to new value passed as argument
   // after this line is executed, value of all subscriptions will change to the latest value
   this.isManager$.next(value); 

   // sets local storage's value to new value
   // in case user reloads page, constructor will set isManager$ to last available value
   localStorage.setItem('isManager', value);
 }

 getIsManager(): Observable<boolean> {
   // returns stream of values, which means, after you've subscribed, you'll always get the latest value from stream
   return this.isManager$;
 }
}
```

To learn more about `BehaviourSubject` check out [RxJS documentation for BehaviourSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject). You can also watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnwjU06yoEE&t=299s) which gives really good explanation of basics of `BehaviourSubject` and how to use them.

Comment: I tried this and it still reads the local storage just once!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
const isManager = localStorage.getItem('isManager') === 'true';
// You need to convert the string stored in local storage to a boolean.

if (isManager) {
  this.doNavigation(isManager);
}
```

What is the point of using of to create an observable that is mapped to undefined? Very smelly code.